# Adiciona consulta WITH dentro de outra consulta - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, como adicionar a consulta abaixo como uma subconsulta.

Consulta com WITH:

```
WITH dias AS(
  SELECT CAST('2017-06-26' AS DATE) AS dia
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d.dia)
    FROM dias d
   WHERE d.dia < '2017-06-30'
)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, d.dia, 103) AS data_cancelado,
       COUNT(s.solid) AS cancelados
  FROM dias d
       LEFT JOIN solicitacao s ON CONVERT(DATE, s.soldatafechamento, 103) = d.dia
                              AND s.proid = 4
                              AND s.solestagioid = 110
GROUP BY d.dia
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Outra Consulta, onde nessa é para colocar a consulta de cima, pois será gerada outra coluna com a query acima.

```
select
CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData,103) [DATA],
COUNT (S.SolID) [Abertos]

from Solicitacao S
where S.ProID = 4 and S.SolData between '26-06-2017' and '30-06-2017' and S.SolTipID = 35

GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData,103)
```

É para sair dessa maneira

```
Data           Abertos        Cancelados
26-06-2017       0                2
27-06-2017       2                1
28-06-2017       5                0
29-06-2017       4                0
30-06-2017       0                4
```

Comment: Como estão declaradas as colunas SolDataFechamento e SolData? Se estiverem declaradas como `datetime`, elas contêm somente a data ou contêm data e horário?

Comment: Uma mesma linha pode ter SolData e SolDataFechamento no período de emissão, ter SolEstagioID = 110 e ter SolTipID = 35? // Por exemplo:  pode ter solicitação aberta no dia 27/6 e cancelada em 29/6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Renan, eis sugestão tratando os casos de aberturas e cancelamentos, de forma individual. Uma CTE para cada tipo de caso.

```
-- código #2 
--> informe datas inicial e final (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @dataInicial date, @dataFinal date;
set @dataInicial= convert(date, '26/6/2017', 103);
set @dataFinal= convert(date, '30/6/2017', 103);

with 
-- contabiliza cancelamentos
cteCancelados as (
SELECT convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103) as SolDataFechamento,
       count(SolID) as Cancelados
  from Solicitacao
  where ProID = 4 
        and SolEstagioID = 110
        and convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103) between @dataInicial and @dataFinal 
  group by convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103)
),
-- contabiliza aberturas
cteAbertos as (
SELECT convert(date, SolData, 103) as SolData,
       count(SolID) as Abertos
  from Solicitacao
  where ProID = 4 
        and SolTipID = 35
        and convert(date, SolData, 103) between @dataInicial and @dataFinal 
  group by convert(date, SolData, 103)
),
-- gera período
cteDatas as (
SELECT @dataInicial as dataPeríodo
union all
SELECT dateadd(day, +1, dataPeríodo)
  from cteDatas 
  where dataPeríodo < @dataFinal
)
SELECT convert(char(10), D.dataPeríodo, 103) as [Data],
       coalesce(A.Abertos, 0) as Abertos,
       coalesce(C.Cancelados, 0) as Cancelados
  from cteDatas as D
       left join cteCancelados as C on C.SolDataFechamento = D.dataPeríodo
       left join cteAbertos as A on A.SolData = D.dataPeríodo;
```

O período de emissão é informado logo no início do código, o que evita a necessidade de modificar no meio do código para alterar o período de emissão. Isto facilita a manutenção do código.

A cláusula WHERE, presente em cada CTE, filtra as linhas necessárias, reduzindo assim o volume de linhas a processar pelo GROUP BY (operador `Stream Aggregate`).

---

Caso as colunas SolData e SolDataFechamento estejam declaradas como *datetime*, você pode alterar:

```
- convert(date, SolDataFechamento, 103) para cast(SolDataFechamento as date)
- convert(date, SolData, 103) para cast(SolData as date)
```

Isto torna a cláusula WHERE *sargable*.

Comment: Show de Bola @JoséDiz

Answer (score 0):

Apenas altere a condição do `JOIN` para fazer parte de um `CASE`:

```
WITH dias AS(
  SELECT CAST('2017-06-26' AS DATE) AS dia
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d.dia)
    FROM dias d
   WHERE d.dia < '2017-06-30'
)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, d.dia, 103) AS data,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.soltipid = 35 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS abertos,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.solestagioid = 110 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cancelados
  FROM dias d
       LEFT JOIN solicitacao s ON CONVERT(DATE, s.soldatafechamento, 103) = d.dia
                              AND s.proid = 4
GROUP BY d.dia
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[**Aqui**](https://github.com/Sorackb/StackOverflowPT/blob/master/MSSQL/Query%20para%20pegar%20palavra%20apos%20determinado%20caractere%20(97102).sql) você confere o `script` utilizado para testar a resposta.

**Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f53d9/1)**

Comment: Muitissimo Obrigado mestre @Sorack